# Google Sheet Filter (display rows) by condition consist of MULTIPLE texts

Tags: google-sheets, keyword

I'm beginner on Google Sheets.
I know there is custom filter that can display rows by condition consist text (that search for specific word).
But there is a way to display rows that consist only multiple "words" in each rows (for example it displays rows that consist of "banana" and "orrange" AT ONCE in each rows) or display rows that consist at least one of "words" in each rows (for example it displays rows that consist of "banana" OR "orange") ??? Or eventually make a check boxes that filter these words like in picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xDXm.png)

Next question: How to make a "filter" that search for specific "keywords" in text in one column and copy these "keywords" in another column: for example A2 consist of text: "This is apple and orange" and some function copy keywords "apple" and "orange" into A3 column -> "apple; orange"

[image]